# Is logout option needed for a desktop application

Tags: security-testing

I am testing an application which generates security certificates. I need to login with appropriate credentials to access the application. I don't see an option to logout. Is logout needed for desktop applications, or just exiting/ closing the application is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If the program has a concept of an account and asks to log in at some point, then it should have a corresponding option to log out and/or switch accounts.

If it doesn't have a concept of an account, then what are you expecting it to log out of?

Comment: A login is required to access the application in which case a logout is required was my assumption, wanted to clarify the same. Thanks for your answer.